# blender 2.8 switch between cycles and eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, experimental-features

I know 2.8 is not yet released.
However I am at the limits of what blender 2.79 can do.
So I wonder how to set the recent 2.8 builds into cycles mode?

Comment: Why the downvotes here? This question isn't unclear. Just because this is obvious in 2.79, does *not* mean it is the same in 2.8

Comment: @X-27 Probably because any answer about 2.8 will likely be outdated pretty quickly due to the fact it's only just started heavy development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a version of blender still in development.

Comment: Blender is always in developement, question around versions are pretty valid for a large part of the comunity who work width last builds.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

Here you go, this image is from Blender 2.8 BETA, just go to right panel and look at the little icons for the one that says "Render" when mouse hover it.

Answer (score 11):

> As of april 2018 the top bar is still work in progress, as most of blender 2.8, so this answer might be temporary or might make no sense at a later date.

The render engine has been moved (at least for now) to the scene section of  the properties window.

[image]

It is hard to know if this change will be permanent, as 2.8 has not been released and it is constantly changing.

Tomorrow might be in a different place... who knows.